# How to connect properly to Google Cloud SQL using Pentaho Kettle

Tags: mysql, cloud, database-connection, kettle

Good day,

I have just started using Pentaho's Kettle to try and connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance. I've noticed that after making the connection, the Test on Spoon says it's working, However, despite that the connection 'connects', it cannot pull the metadata about the tables or schemas inside.

Yes, I did enable the google sql tool before hand, which, by documentation says, allows 3rd party programs to access the Google App cloud. However, as I said, it can't seem to find any tables despite being able to 'connect'.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem with the help of someone from work. He posted our findings here. :) I hope it helps. It involves actually adding in JARs to your spoon

http://lorenzo-dee.blogspot.com/2013/04/kettle-pentaho-data-integration.html